# Python error "Connection reset by peer" in requests module

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, session-cookies

My goal is to create a persistent cookie on-the-fly by supplying user id & password and use that cookie in POST request using a session object. But below code returns below exception.

('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

class CreatePersistentCookie(): """This class is created to generate a persistent cookie that can further be used through out session for all the service requests being executed"""

```
class CreatePersistentCookie():
    """This class is created to generate a persistent cookie that can further be
       used through out session for all the service requests being executed"""

    def __init__(self, headers, data, url, params, authserver):
        self.headers = headers
        self.data = data
        self.url = url
        self.params = params
        self.authserver = authserver

    def generateCookie(self):
        with requests.session() as s:
            reqsessionObj = s.post(self.authserver,params = self.params)
            reqCookie = reqsessionObj.request.headers['Cookie'] # this returns the Cookie i need
            regexObj = re.compile(r'act-uat=\S+') # this is my app specific pattern search that returns the exact cookie text i need.
            matchObj = regexObj.search(reqCookie)
            sessionCookie = matchObj.group()
            self.headers['Cookie'] = sessionCookie # adding Cookie attribute in headers.
            try:
                r = s.post(self.url, data=json.dumps(self.data), headers=self.headers)
                return r.raise_for_status()
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
                print err

def main():

    # Defining the params variable. This contains authentication details such as user id,password & App id.
    params = {"accountId": "John",
             "accountPassword": "password",
             "appIdKey": "5c9773e36fd6ea7cc2f9f8ffd9da3e3"
            }
    # Defining the authserver variable that contains the host details where authentication happens.
    authserver = 'https://auth-uat.com/authenticate'

    # creating a object cookieObj from class CreatePersistentCookie that returns persistent cookie.
    #print cookies
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Host':'service-uat1.com'}

    data = {"appName":"abc","appKey":"abc","type":"jdbc","queryName":"xyz","version":"v1.2","useCache":"false","bindVars":[{"bindVarName":"In_dt","bindVarVal":"2014-05-13"},{"bindVarName":"In_Location","bindVarVal":"USA"}]}
    url = 'https://uat1.com/gsf/abc/derf/abc/services/xyz'

    cookieObj = CreatePersistentCookie(headers, data, url, params, authserver)

    cookieObj.generateCookie()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Connection reset by peer indicates that the server you're trying to connect to is refusing the connection. Normally, there is a handshake between your computer and the website's server, but here for some reason, the server is refusing the connection. I would use the urllib, requests, mechanize, and cookielib modules (some of which only work in Python 2.7). Then, using urllib you can attach a user-client header like Firefox, which will trick the browser into accepting the connection because they will think you are a regular person surfing the web, not a robot.

Comment: This is what solved my issue. Using requests (python package), I copied the request headers from Safari and used those headers to send the request, and stopped getting Connection Reset By Peer errors. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

```
headers = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command in terminal it worked for me

```
pip install requests[security]
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation what is this for? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked from Postman but not from python script. Restarting the system fixed it.